# Count all numbers in php string

Tags: php, string, count

How can I count all numbers in string to get their sum?
Example string:

```
G12103108 : 0.00 Troy oz. | U20072491 : 12.10 USD | U27811285 : 0.55 USD | U41125827 : 0.00 USD | U47329193 : 0.00 USD | E30010787 : 10.01 EUR
```

How can I get the result?

```
22.66
```

I tried

```
count(array_filter(str_split($str),'is_numeric'));
```

with no luck

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: tried count(array_filter(str_split($str),'is_numeric')); with no luck

Comment: either regex things or explode on '|', remove everything before ' : ' and everything after another space. Add values up

Comment: Eventually [`preg_match_all ()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) may help you

Comment: Explode is not what I'm looking for. I need to identify all numbers in any string of integer and float types. Can you help with regex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for you:

(Here i simply use [`preg_match_all()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) to get all float numbers after `:`. And after that i count all values together with [`array_sum()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php))

```
<?php

    $str = "G12103108 : 0.00 Troy oz. | U20072491 : 12.10 USD | U27811285 : 0.55 USD | U41125827 : 0.00 USD | U47329193 : 0.00 USD | E30010787 : 10.01 EUR";
    preg_match_all('!:\s(\d+\.*\d*)!', $str, $matches);
    echo array_sum($matches[1]);

?>
```

Output:

```
22.66
```

Comment: @user1482261 You're welcome! Have a nice day :D (Hope you understand everything what i did, otherwise just ask)